# error CS1703: Multiple assemblies with equivalent identity have been imported - Drawing.dll

Tags: unity-game-engine

So I've been struggling with this for the past few hours...
I'm trying to use a project I got online: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gOZ8Z0mDgGA

But I'm currently running into the following issue:

```
error CS1703: Multiple assemblies with equivalent identity have been imported: 'O:\UnityProjects\EmotionFacialRecognition\EmotionDetectionAsset_UnityDemo-master\Assets\System.Drawing.dll' and 'C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.2.11f1\Editor\Data\NetStandard\compat\2.0.0\shims\netfx\System.Drawing.dll'. Remove one of the duplicate references.
```

Does anyone know how to resolve this error?

Edit: The following link doesn't seem to make any changes:
["Multiple assemblies with equivalent identity have been imported" in VS2015 with a Unity generated csproj](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50399959/multiple-assemblies-with-equivalent-identity-have-been-imported-in-vs2015-with)

Unity version: 2019.2.11f1
Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Multiple assemblies with equivalent identity have been imported" in VS2015 with a Unity generated csproj](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50399959/multiple-assemblies-with-equivalent-identity-have-been-imported-in-vs2015-with)

Comment: @KenWhite I have tried to create the ProjectFileHook.cs script and pasted the code - but nothing seems to have changed

Answer (score 0):

I found the following solution on another post, which worked!
Credit to @veuncent

For me it worked to remove the reference to both assemblies and re-add them again.

Expand your project's References in the Solution Explorer --> Right click the faulty assembly -> Remove.

Then right click References -> Add Reference... -> check the boxes of the assemblies you just removed.

Then rebuild.